# parsings strings: extracting words and phrases [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I need to support exact phrases (enclosed in quotes) in an otherwise space-separated list of terms.
Thus splitting the respective string by the space-character is not sufficient anymore.

Example:

```
input : 'foo bar "lorem ipsum" baz'
output: ['foo', 'bar', 'lorem ipsum', 'baz']
```

I wonder whether this could be achieved with a single RegEx, rather than performing complex parsing or split-and-rejoin operations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var str = 'foo bar "lorem ipsum" baz';  
var results = str.match(/("[^"]+"|[^"\s]+)/g);
```

... returns the array you're looking for.
Note, however:

- Bounding quotes are included, so can be removed with `replace(/^"([^"]+)"$/,"$1")` on the results.
- Spaces between the quotes will stay intact. So, if there are three spaces between `lorem` and `ipsum`, they'll be in the result. You can fix this by running `replace(/\s+/," ")` on the results.
- If there's no closing `"` after `ipsum` (i.e. an incorrectly-quoted phrase) you'll end up with: `['foo', 'bar', 'lorem', 'ipsum', 'baz']`

Comment: The only problem with this is that all quotes are stripped - i.e. quote characters themselves are not searchable.

Comment: Fine, only dont find scape quote, like this:    ['foo', 'bar', 'lorem \' ipsum', 'baz']

Comment: nice! this is a simple way to implement a search engine parser for searching for phrases and single words... much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I posted my implementation of a search engine parser for phrases and single words as another answer, where phrases are treated as regular expressions.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var input = 'foo bar "lorem ipsum" baz';
var R =  /(\w|\s)*\w(?=")|\w+/g;
var output = input.match(R);

output is ["foo", "bar", "lorem ipsum", "baz"]
```

Note there are no extra double quotes around lorem ipsum

Although it assumes the input has the double quotes in the right place:

```
var input2 = 'foo bar lorem ipsum" baz'; var output2 = input2.match(R);
var input3 = 'foo bar "lorem ipsum baz'; var output3 = input3.match(R);

output2 is ["foo bar lorem ipsum", "baz"]
output3 is ["foo", "bar", "lorem", "ipsum", "baz"]
```

And won't handle escaped double quotes (is that a problem?):

```
var input4 = 'foo b\"ar  bar\" \"bar "lorem ipsum" baz';
var output4 = input4.match(R);

output4 is  ["foo b", "ar bar", "bar", "lorem ipsum", "baz"]
```

Comment: To make this work for Unicode numbers and letters, use `\p{L}\p{N}` in place of `\w`.

Comment: This is a neat approach. But (like the others) doesn't allow some reasonable punctuation characters in words, for example `#hashtag`, `@mention`, `couldn't` or `123.456`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple regular expression will do but leave the quotation marks. e.g.

```
'foo bar "lorem ipsum" baz'.match(/("[^"]*")|([^\s"]+)/g)
output:   ['foo', 'bar', '"lorem ipsum"', 'baz']
```

edit: beaten to it by shyamsundar, sorry for the double answer

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for the quick responses!

Here's a summary of the options, for posterity:

```
var input = 'foo bar "lorem ipsum" baz';

output = input.match(/("[^"]+"|[^"\s]+)/g);
output = input.match(/"[^"]*"|\w+/g);
output = input.match(/("[^"]*")|([^\s"]+)/g)
output = /(".+?"|\w+)/g.exec(input);
output = /"(.+?)"|(\w+)/g.exec(input);
```

For the record, here's the abomination I had come up with:

```
var input = 'foo bar "lorem ipsum" "dolor sit amet" baz';
var terms = input.split(" ");

var items = [];
var buffer = [];
for(var i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
    if(terms[i].indexOf('"') != -1) { // outer phrase fragment -- N.B.: assumes quote is either first or last character
        if(buffer.length === 0) { // beginning of phrase
            //console.log("start:", terms[i]);
            buffer.push(terms[i].substr(1));
        } else { // end of phrase
            //console.log("end:", terms[i]);
            buffer.push(terms[i].substr(0, terms[i].length - 1));
            items.push(buffer.join(" "));
            buffer = [];
        }
    } else if(buffer.length != 0) { // inner phrase fragment
        //console.log("cont'd:", terms[i]);
        buffer.push(terms[i]);
    } else { // individual term
        //console.log("standalone:", terms[i]);
        items.push(terms[i]);
    }
    //console.log(items, "\n", buffer);
}
items = items.concat(buffer);

//console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'foo bar "lorem ipsum" baz'.match(/"[^"]*"|\w+/g);
```

the bounding quotes get included though

Answer (score 1):

how about,

```
output = /(".+?"|\w+)/g.exec(input)
```

then do a pass on output to lose the quotes.

alternately,

```
output = /"(.+?)"|(\w+)/g.exec(input)
```

then do a pass n output to lose the empty captures.

Answer (score 1):

ES6 solution supporting:

- Split by space except for inside quotes
- Removing quotes but not for backslash escaped quotes
- Escaped quote become quote

Code:

```
input.match(/\\?.|^$/g).reduce((p, c) => {
        if(c === '"'){
            p.quote ^= 1;
        }else if(!p.quote && c === ' '){
            p.a.push('');
        }else{
            p.a[p.a.length-1] += c.replace(/\\(.)/,"$1");
        }
        return  p;
    }, {a: ['']}).a
```

Output:

```
[ 'foo', 'bar', 'lorem ipsum', 'baz' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

One that's easy to understand and a general solution. Works for all delimiters and 'join' characters. Also supports 'joined' words that are more than two words in length.... ie lists like

`"hello my name is 'jon delaware smith fred' I have a 'long name'"`....

A bit like the answer by AC but a bit neater...

```
function split(input, delimiter, joiner){
    var output = [];
    var joint = [];
    input.split(delimiter).forEach(function(element){
        if (joint.length > 0 && element.indexOf(joiner) === element.length - 1)
        {
            output.push(joint.join(delimiter) + delimiter + element);
            joint = [];
        }
        if (joint.length > 0 || element.indexOf(joiner) === 0)
        {
            joint.push(element);
        }
        if (joint.length === 0 && element.indexOf(joiner) !== element.length - 1)
        {
            output.push(element);
            joint = [];
        }
    });
    return output;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a very late answer, but I am interested in answering

```
([\w]+|\"[\w\s]+\")
```

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/72

Pure javascript example

```
 'The rain in "SPAIN stays" mainly in the plain'.match(/[\w]+|\"[\w\s]+\"/g)
```

Outputs:

```
["The", "rain", "in", ""SPAIN stays"", "mainly", "in", "the", "plain"]
```

Comment: This is not unicode friendly, for instance it won't support Arabic characters.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the accepted answer, here's a search engine parser that,

- can match phrases or words
- treats phrases as regular expressions
- does a boolean OR across multiple properties (e.g. item.title and item.body)
- handles negation of words or phrases when they are prefixed with -

Treating phrases as regular expressions makes the UI simpler for my purposes.

```js
const matchOrIncludes = (str, search, useMatch = true) => {
  if (useMatch) {
    let result = false
    try {
      result = str.match(search)
    } catch (err) {
      return false
    }
    return result
  }
  return str.includes(search)
}


const itemMatches = (item, searchString, fields) => {
  const keywords = searchString.toString().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').trim().toLocaleLowerCase().match(/(-?"[^"]+"|[^"\s]+)/g) || []
  for (let i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
    const negateWord = keywords[i].startsWith('-') ? true : false
    let word = keywords[i].replace(/^-/,'')
    const isPhraseRegex = word.startsWith('"') ? true : false
    if (isPhraseRegex) {
      word = word.replace(/^"(.+)"$/,"$1")
    }
    let word_in_item = false
    for (const field of fields) {
      if (item[field] && matchOrIncludes(item[field].toLocaleLowerCase(), word, isPhraseRegex)) {
        word_in_item = true
        break
      }
    }
    if ((! negateWord && ! word_in_item) || (negateWord && word_in_item)) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}

const item = {title: 'My title', body: 'Some text'}
console.log(itemMatches(item, 'text', ['title', 'body']))
```