# How to split a string by ":" but keep the parts in quotes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex which splits a string by `:` but don't split the quoted parts:

```
'a:b:c'.split(/*RegExNeeded*/) // => ['a','b','c']
'a:"1:2":d'.split(/*RegExNeeded*/) // => ['a','1:2', 'd']
```

I've tried `''.split(':')` but it is not working, because it'll split the `1:2` as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64904/parsings-strings-extracting-words-and-phrases-javascript

Comment: You could do it in two steps.  One split by one separator, then each of the split elements, split by the second separator

Comment: This is basically the same as a CSV parser (albeit a colon in place of a comma). Have you checked out any of the many CSV parsers to see if they support different separators (hint: they do)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use look ahead to ensure that the number of double quotes that follows a colon is even (not odd):

```js
var res = 'a:"1:2":d'.split(/:(?=[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)/);
console.log(res.join());
```